# OAuth LTI Error: Request not validating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, lti

I am trying to upgrade a legacy app to use the 2.2 version of the LTI ruby gem.

Currently, I cannot get Oauth requests to validate using the following:

```
authenticator = IMS::LTI::Services::MessageAuthenticator.new(@request.url, @params, secret)
authenticator.valid_signature?
```

I'm not sure what is causing this, as it should be a valid request, as far as I can tell. Here are dumps of the variables involved:

App 9783 stdout: --- OAUTH Key ====> ocill-lti-key
App 9783 stdout: --- OAUTH Secret ====> REDACTED!
App 9783 stdout: --- REQUEST URL https://lrc-tesuto.lrc.lsa.umich.edu/ocill/launch/create
App 9783 stdout: --- REQUEST PARAMS {"oauth_consumer_key"=>"ocill-lti-key", "oauth_signature_method"=>"HMAC-SHA1", "oauth_timestamp"=>"1510067228", "oauth_nonce"=>"70h3qDQemquvfZeKZ03OIJt5Me06hmoUuA4DEscIgQ", "oauth_version"=>"1.0", "context_id"=>"de25c863939f3cacfc02480738d072d95597842c", "context_label"=>"johnathb Sandbox", "context_title"=>"A Canvas training course for johnathb", "custom_canvas_assignment_points_possible"=>"10", "custom_canvas_assignment_title"=>"OCILL Staging Test", "custom_canvas_enrollment_state"=>"active", "ext_ims_lis_basic_outcome_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/ext_grade_passback", "ext_lti_assignment_id"=>"f9139721-be1f-473a-91b5-6a08a386074c", "ext_outcome_data_values_accepted"=>"url,text", "ext_outcome_result_total_score_accepted"=>"true", "ext_outcomes_tool_placement_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/turnitin/outcomes_placement/10530", "ext_roles"=>"urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Administrator,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Student,urn:lti:role:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:sysrole:ims/lis/User", "launch_presentation_document_target"=>"iframe", "launch_presentation_locale"=>"en", "launch_presentation_return_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/courses/56125/external_content/success/external_tool_redirect", "lis_outcome_service_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/grade_passback", "lti_message_type"=>"basic-lti-launch-request", "lti_version"=>"LTI-1p0", "oauth_callback"=>"about:blank", "resource_link_id"=>"52e0499f9ed929340aec886dd08c7035e45471f5", "resource_link_title"=>"OCILL Staging Test", "roles"=>"Instructor", "tool_consumer_info_product_family_code"=>"canvas", "tool_consumer_info_version"=>"cloud", "tool_consumer_instance_contact_email"=>"notifications@instructure.com", "tool_consumer_instance_guid"=>"7db438071375c02373713c12c73869ff2f470b68.umich.instructure.com", "tool_consumer_instance_name"=>"University of Michigan - Ann Arbor", "user_id"=>"1ec00186b63b783a994fd2d5b7648ba6cdfe9807", "oauth_signature"=>"7jq4lBIBYoMzIeShPZbPNJjOrEs=", "controller"=>"launch", "action"=>"create"}

App 9783 stdout: --- AUTHENTICATOR INSPECT ===> #"ocill-lti-key", "oauth_signature_method"=>"HMAC-SHA1", "oauth_timestamp"=>"1510067228", "oauth_nonce"=>"70h3qDQemquvfZeKZ03OIJt5Me06hmoUuA4DEscIgQ", "oauth_version"=>"1.0", "context_id"=>"de25c863939f3cacfc02480738d072d95597842c", "context_label"=>"johnathb Sandbox", "context_title"=>"A Canvas training course for johnathb", "custom_canvas_assignment_points_possible"=>"10", "custom_canvas_assignment_title"=>"OCILL Staging Test", "custom_canvas_enrollment_state"=>"active", "ext_ims_lis_basic_outcome_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/ext_grade_passback", "ext_lti_assignment_id"=>"f9139721-be1f-473a-91b5-6a08a386074c", "ext_outcome_data_values_accepted"=>"url,text", "ext_outcome_result_total_score_accepted"=>"true", "ext_outcomes_tool_placement_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/turnitin/outcomes_placement/10530", "ext_roles"=>"urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Administrator,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Student,urn:lti:role:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:sysrole:ims/lis/User", "launch_presentation_document_target"=>"iframe", "launch_presentation_locale"=>"en", "launch_presentation_return_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/courses/56125/external_content/success/external_tool_redirect", "lis_outcome_service_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/grade_passback", "lti_message_type"=>"basic-lti-launch-request", "lti_version"=>"LTI-1p0", "oauth_callback"=>"about:blank", "resource_link_id"=>"52e0499f9ed929340aec886dd08c7035e45471f5", "resource_link_title"=>"OCILL Staging Test", "roles"=>"Instructor", "tool_consumer_info_product_family_code"=>"canvas", "tool_consumer_info_version"=>"cloud", "tool_consumer_instance_contact_email"=>"notifications@instructure.com", "tool_consumer_instance_guid"=>"7db438071375c02373713c12c73869ff2f470b68.umich.instructure.com", "tool_consumer_instance_name"=>"University of Michigan - Ann Arbor", "user_id"=>"1ec00186b63b783a994fd2d5b7648ba6cdfe9807", "oauth_signature"=>"7jq4lBIBYoMzIeShPZbPNJjOrEs=", "controller"=>"launch", "action"=>"create"}, @options={:consumer_key=>"ocill-lti-key", :signature_method=>"HMAC-SHA1", :timestamp=>"1510067228", :nonce=>"70h3qDQemquvfZeKZ03OIJt5Me06hmoUuA4DEscIgQ", :version=>"1.0", :callback=>"about:blank"}, @parsed_params={:context_id=>"de25c863939f3cacfc02480738d072d95597842c", :context_label=>"johnathb Sandbox", :context_title=>"A Canvas training course for johnathb", :custom_canvas_assignment_points_possible=>"10", :custom_canvas_assignment_title=>"OCILL Staging Test", :custom_canvas_enrollment_state=>"active", :ext_ims_lis_basic_outcome_url=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/ext_grade_passback", :ext_lti_assignment_id=>"f9139721-be1f-473a-91b5-6a08a386074c", :ext_outcome_data_values_accepted=>"url,text", :ext_outcome_result_total_score_accepted=>"true", :ext_outcomes_tool_placement_url=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/turnitin/outcomes_placement/10530", :ext_roles=>"urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Administrator,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Student,urn:lti:role:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:sysrole:ims/lis/User", :launch_presentation_document_target=>"iframe", :launch_presentation_locale=>"en", :launch_presentation_return_url=>"https://umich.instructure.com/courses/56125/external_content/success/external_tool_redirect", :lis_outcome_service_url=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/grade_passback", :lti_message_type=>"basic-lti-launch-request", :lti_version=>"LTI-1p0", :resource_link_id=>"52e0499f9ed929340aec886dd08c7035e45471f5", :resource_link_title=>"OCILL Staging Test", :roles=>"Instructor", :tool_consumer_info_product_family_code=>"canvas", :tool_consumer_info_version=>"cloud", :tool_consumer_instance_contact_email=>"notifications@instructure.com", :tool_consumer_instance_guid=>"7db438071375c02373713c12c73869ff2f470b68.umich.instructure.com", :tool_consumer_instance_name=>"University of Michigan - Ann Arbor", :user_id=>"1ec00186b63b783a994fd2d5b7648ba6cdfe9807", :controller=>"launch", :action=>"create"}, @consumer_key="ocill-lti-key", @Signature="7jq4lBIBYoMzIeShPZbPNJjOrEs=", @secret="REDACTED!", @message=#"10", "custom_canvas_assignment_title"=>"OCILL Staging Test", "custom_canvas_enrollment_state"=>"active"}, @ext_params={"ext_ims_lis_basic_outcome_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/ext_grade_passback", "ext_lti_assignment_id"=>"f9139721-be1f-473a-91b5-6a08a386074c", "ext_outcome_data_values_accepted"=>"url,text", "ext_outcome_result_total_score_accepted"=>"true", "ext_outcomes_tool_placement_url"=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/turnitin/outcomes_placement/10530", "ext_roles"=>"urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Administrator,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Student,urn:lti:role:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:sysrole:ims/lis/User"}, @unknown_params={"controller"=>"launch", "action"=>"create"}, @oauth_consumer_key="ocill-lti-key", @oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", @oauth_timestamp="1510067228", @oauth_nonce="70h3qDQemquvfZeKZ03OIJt5Me06hmoUuA4DEscIgQ", @oauth_version="1.0", @context_id="de25c863939f3cacfc02480738d072d95597842c", @context_label="johnathb Sandbox", @context_title="A Canvas training course for johnathb", @launch_presentation_document_target="iframe", @launch_presentation_locale="en", @launch_presentation_return_url="https://umich.instructure.com/courses/56125/external_content/success/external_tool_redirect", @lis_outcome_service_url="https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/grade_passback", @lti_message_type="basic-lti-launch-request", @lti_version="LTI-1p0", @oauth_callback="about:blank", @resource_link_id="52e0499f9ed929340aec886dd08c7035e45471f5", @resource_link_title="OCILL Staging Test", @roles="Instructor", @tool_consumer_info_product_family_code="canvas", @tool_consumer_info_version="cloud", @tool_consumer_instance_contact_email="notifications@instructure.com", @tool_consumer_instance_guid="7db438071375c02373713c12c73869ff2f470b68.umich.instructure.com", @tool_consumer_instance_name="University of Michigan - Ann Arbor", @user_id="1ec00186b63b783a994fd2d5b7648ba6cdfe9807", @oauth_signature="7jq4lBIBYoMzIeShPZbPNJjOrEs=", @launch_url="https://lrc-tesuto.lrc.lsa.umich.edu/ocill/launch/create">, @simple_oauth_header=#https://lrc-tesuto.lrc.lsa.umich.edu/ocill/launch/create>, @params={:context_id=>"de25c863939f3cacfc02480738d072d95597842c", :context_label=>"johnathb Sandbox", :context_title=>"A Canvas training course for johnathb", :custom_canvas_assignment_points_possible=>"10", :custom_canvas_assignment_title=>"OCILL Staging Test", :custom_canvas_enrollment_state=>"active", :ext_ims_lis_basic_outcome_url=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/ext_grade_passback", :ext_lti_assignment_id=>"f9139721-be1f-473a-91b5-6a08a386074c", :ext_outcome_data_values_accepted=>"url,text", :ext_outcome_result_total_score_accepted=>"true", :ext_outcomes_tool_placement_url=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/turnitin/outcomes_placement/10530", :ext_roles=>"urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Administrator,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:instrole:ims/lis/Student,urn:lti:role:ims/lis/Instructor,urn:lti:sysrole:ims/lis/User", :launch_presentation_document_target=>"iframe", :launch_presentation_locale=>"en", :launch_presentation_return_url=>"https://umich.instructure.com/courses/56125/external_content/success/external_tool_redirect", :lis_outcome_service_url=>"https://umich.instructure.com/api/lti/v1/tools/10530/grade_passback", :lti_message_type=>"basic-lti-launch-request", :lti_version=>"LTI-1p0", :resource_link_id=>"52e0499f9ed929340aec886dd08c7035e45471f5", :resource_link_title=>"OCILL Staging Test", :roles=>"Instructor", :tool_consumer_info_product_family_code=>"canvas", :tool_consumer_info_version=>"cloud", :tool_consumer_instance_contact_email=>"notifications@instructure.com", :tool_consumer_instance_guid=>"7db438071375c02373713c12c73869ff2f470b68.umich.instructure.com", :tool_consumer_instance_name=>"University of Michigan - Ann Arbor", :user_id=>"1ec00186b63b783a994fd2d5b7648ba6cdfe9807", :controller=>"launch", :action=>"create"}, @options={:nonce=>"70h3qDQemquvfZeKZ03OIJt5Me06hmoUuA4DEscIgQ", :signature_method=>"HMAC-SHA1", :timestamp=>"1510067228", :version=>"1.0", :consumer_key=>"ocill-lti-key", :callback=>"about:blank", :consumer_secret=>"REDACTED!"}>>

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I had extra parameters in my request that were being passed in.

Used the following to generate params for the validator instead:

```
params = request.query_parameters.merge(request.request_parameters)
```